# Using name as a location instead of coordinate for google

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to pin a marker on the map base on the name instead of coordinate ?

Such as

```
echo'<iframe width="550" height="280" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place key=AIzaSyB412H_qOVZ3u6awLH6Rovvhbv6qA35LSg&q= China"></iframe>';
```

Instead of

```
var coba2center = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.78793,110.36933);
var coba2marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:coba2center,
    });
```

Or would it be possible to do this

```
var location= "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place key=AIzaSyB412H_qOVZ3u6awLH6Rovvhbv6qA35LSg&q= China"

var coba2center = new google.maps.location;
var coba2marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:coba2center,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "place" names or addresses for positions in the Google Maps Javascript API v3, you need to use coordinates. But there are services for translating place names ([the Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)) and addresses to coordinates ([the geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding))

Comment: if i want to toggle between different location with buttons, what will be the best way to do so.